# SQL Server async procedure execution: how to pass varbinary(MAX)?

Tags: sql-server, asynchronous, service-broker

I read and know this great solution from Remus Rusanu for the async stored procedures execution

https://github.com/rusanu/async_tsql

What is the good way to exec a stored procedure with a parameter of type `varbinary(MAX)`?

How to implement this kind of async procedures calls?

Comment: Why exactly did you have a problem with calling a stored procedure with `varbinary(max)` parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the `sql_variant` technique in his article to accomplish this, unfortunately.  However, nothing stops you from declaring your Service Broker message as `VALIDATION = NONE`:

```
CREATE MESSAGE TYPE
    [//Adventure-Works.com/Expenses/ReceiptImage]
    VALIDATION = NONE ;
```

This allows you send freeform binary data as the message and pass it directly to your processing procedure.  It's certainly more limited if you're going to send anything *other* than a single `varbinary(max)`, but for what you are asking for it will work.